# How to calculate effect size based on percentage and sample size?

Tags: sample-size, effect-size, percentage

In an intervention study, I have the following information - % of students passing an exam pre- and post intervention, sample size for control group and intervention group at pre- and post intervention, how can I work out the effect size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem amounts to a $2\times 2$ contingency table (actually 2 such tables if you look at pre- and post-intervention).  The variable for the columns could be the pass/fail counts, and the variable for the rows could be the treatment condition (control & intervention).

Assuming appropriate conditions have been met, this is a chi-square analysis, and the conventional effect size here is the phi-coefficient:
$$\phi = \sqrt{\frac{\chi^2}{N}}$$
(Curiously, this also happens to be the correlation if you code the two variables as ones and zeros.)

The convention with this effect size is to classify with the cut-offs of 0.1, 0.3, and 0.5, for small, moderate, and large, respectively.

---

**Update #1**
Based on the information provided in the comments, this would better be described as a 4×2 contingency table.  The first variable is the treatment condition (dichotomous), and the second variable is the the pre/post status description.  You would have 4 conditions for this variable: achieved at pre and failed to achieve at post, failed to achieve at both pre and post, achieved at both pre and post, and failed to achieve at pre and achieved at post (ordered in "best" for substantiating treatment effect).

In this case, you would use the Cramer’s $V$ as the effect size measure:
$$V = \sqrt{\frac{\chi^2}{N \cdot \text{min}(R-1,C-1)}}$$
where $R$ is the number of rows and $C$ is the number of columns in the table.  This effect size is compared to the same cut-offs as the $phi$ coefficient.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. There's one problem with this approach, which is that at baseline, both intervention and control groups had the 'exposure' already. Specifically, the outcome is % of participants meeting the recommended guidelines. So at baseline, a proportion of participants in both groups have already met the guidelines. Unless no one in both groups had met the guidelines at baseline, then the 2x2 frequency table would work. But in this case, 2x2 might not be sufficient to answer the question?

Comment: I'm sorry...I don't know what you mean by having a control group that has been exposed to the treatment...that's not a control group.

Comment: Hi @Gregg H, let me be more specific about the study. It's an intervention to get participants more physically active, with an experimental and a control group. At baseline and post-intervention, the % of participants who have achieved the recommended level of physical activity was measured. For example, at baseline, 20% of the control group and 30% of the experimental group have achieved the recommended level; at post-intervention, 25% of the control and 40% of the experimental group have achieved the recommended level, how do we then calculate the effect size? Hope this is clearer.

Comment: My first recommendation is NOT to use the counts, but to use the metric that is used to classify one as achieved or failed to achieve.  My guess is that this is some scalar measurement.  Then you can calculate the difference of these scores for each individual, and the matched-pairs effect size would be $d = \frac{\bar{d}}{s_d}$ where $\bar{d}$ is the average gain/loss score and $s_d$ is the standard deviation of these scores.  However, if you must use counts, I have added an update to my original answer.

Comment: Many thanks again for the detailed explanation Gregg. It's still tricky to work out the effect size, as the paper only provided the % of each group pre- and post-intervention, without matching the participants at the 2 time points. So there's no information on the no. of participants who met the guideline at pre-/post-, the no. of participants who did not meet the guideline at pre-/post- etc.

Comment: ¿Are there any sample sizes reported in the paper?  If so, you can work the %s back to whole counts.

Comment: Yes, n is provided in the study. However, the counts for those who met the recommendation at pre but didn't meet at post, or for those who met at post but not at pre, cannot be determined in the 4x2 table?

Comment: If you have the overall n and the percent breakdown for treatment and control, then if you have the percent and pre and post, you can indeed calculate all of the counts (within rounding).

Comment: Thanks so much Gregg - I can see what you meant now. Really appreciate all your advice along the way!

Comment: Thnx...if the comments have been useful, remember that you can up-vote those, too.

Comment: We could also use Cohen's $\omega$ for this case (which is essentially $\phi$ for two-way tables larger than 2X2), but it depends a bit on what is the purpose of having an effect size in the first place. If it's for subsequent sample size calculations for future studies, Cohen's $\omega$ may be more appropriate, while on the other hand Cramér's V may be easier to interpret (if ease of interpretation is a feature we want). Anyway, one can easily convert Cramér's V to Cohen's $\omega$ (and conversely), so the choice is not such a big deal ultimately, but I think it's worth mentioning $\omega$.